# Why is Str[fix_num] yielding the wrong result

Tags: ruby, string

I'm trying use the Str[fixnum] to return a specific portion of a string.

```
# Given
Str = "James"

Str[0]
# Should yield `"J"'.
# Instead its yielding `74`.
```

The strange thing is yesterday evening it yielded the "J"

Does anyone have any idea of what might be going on here. Have I inadvertently changed a setting that is causing the function to return the ascii character number. I'm stumped.

Update:  I have confirmed that 74 is in fact the ascii number representation for "J".  So the question is the function return the ascii instead of the actual character.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String#[]` with a single integer `i` as an argument returns the `i`th byte as an integer in ruby 1.8. In ruby 1.9 it returns a one-character string.

So when you tried it yesterday, you were probably using ruby 1.9, while you're using 1.8 today.

To get a one-character string in ruby 1.8, you can use `str[i, 1]`, which has the same behavior in 1.8 and 1.9.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I looks like I'm using Ruby 1.8.7.  I don't know why the version of ruby would have changed overnight.  I'm actually in the same rails console as yesterday.

Comment: If you're using RVM to manage your rubies, you can put a .rvmrc file in your project dir which will switch you into (and later, back out of) the appropriate version.